# Present relevance or not , present perfect or past simple in this case

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-present-perfect

> Sorry to contact you but I just realized that my last order ( two Comps on bin liner) made  on discog were on Cd. I **made** a mistake. I thought they were on vinyl.
>
> So I know that this order has already been sent. Could it be possible to send this order back to you once I have received it. I will pay for the extra cost, of course

I just was wondering if past simple is a good choice or would it be better to use present perfect.

I know the mistake was made when I ordered these comps (about one week ago) so in the past BUT I think  there is a present relevance: I want to re-send this order once I have received it

So I don't know which tense shall I use?

Comment: It's ***much*** better to stick to Simple Past in this context. Firstly because it's nearly always best to avoid Perfect forms if you're in any doubt. But specifically in this case because both the immediately preceding *and* immediately following elements (*order **made** on discog*, *I **made** a mistake*) are focused on the past. You wouldn't normally want Present Perfect when neither what comes before *nor* what comes after explicitly reference *current* time [of speaking or writing].

Comment: Even if you did have a reference to time of utterance (as in ***Can** you* [now] *help? I have made a mistake...,* I wouldn't see any good reason for that Perfect form. Just *I made a mistake...* is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple past is the right choice here.

It's true there is a present result of the action in the past, and that present result is the reason for writing, but in that context, you're telling a story *about the past*, and it doesn't make sense to switch from simple past to a present tense then back to the simple past again.

The topic of that paragraph might be "*I have made a mistake*", but at that point in the story, you're giving details of what happened, which should be told in the past.